# Google Map based on emergency location information

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe, real-time, geohazard

I would like to build a google map where I can see the locations of currently happening emergencies like earthquake, storms, wildfire, etc.

Does anybody know sources from where I can get data like that? Especially for Europe.

Similar services from google itself are available. But not really for Europe.

https://www.google.org/publicalerts

https://www.google.org/crisismap/weather_and_events

Comment: If google has maps like this for the US and not for Europe, it suggests (but does not prove) that it's difficult to obtain or collate such data. Suggestion: try looking at individual European countries first and send out email. Who knows, you may become the best-known compiler of this data :)

Comment: @Patrick, have you looked at http://hisz.rsoe.hu/alertmap/index2.php?area=eu and http://www.globalincidentmap.com/ ?

Comment: not Europe, I know, but Seattle has a real-time 911 API which people have built google maps around http://www.public911.com/app/#/seattle

Comment: Do you have any specific European country in mind? It's probably more useful to search in the native languages.

Comment: @philshem not really. Like to implement multiple webservices for the map. And the U.S. there are ones. But if it helps german would be ok for the beginning.

Comment: @Patrick Just a suggestion, as I feel it fits your request and this was migrated from softwarerecs: Currently, I am getting such data up and running and have recently added [wildfires](https://www.geodata.one/?&uuid=00fdc484f35faf92063a5e412d0110f795f57483) and [earthquakes](https://www.geodata.one/?&uuid=4db508573e389bae543188e1a258153be1015cc5) as WMS. The services are not free, though (services need to be maintained) but those data is open data. If you'd like to put it into a cool map app, I'm open to that. You also might be able to find more data here: www.geodata.one.

Comment: @tareq sounds cool. I would like to see some of the data. Just for your info, its not excluded to use paid services. Are there other services except wildfire and earthquakes which are interesting to me?

Comment: Good to hear. Well, there's e.g. major volcanic eruptions, major tsunami locations (World); current river water levels, wind speed/ direction, rainfall amount, temperature, severe weather warnings, 
current radiation values (Germany). Some are external, some need setup or update. If there's more out there e.g. country-level, I'll definitely add them when I stumble upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the request from philshem in the comments to the question, I will post my comment details as an answer.

**Disclosure:** I am the author of the mentioned website.

As a suggestion, as I feel it fits the question and this was migrated from softwarerecs: Currently, I am getting emergency location data up and running and have recently added [wildfires](https://www.geodata.one/?&uuid=ba540b68103d07096897eb5e479595d50cc27b61&layer=viirs_active_fires__last_24h_gd_166&linkId=0&ds=narimo%20web%20map%20service%20-%20NASA%20products&lang=de&rp=NASA) and [earthquakes](https://www.geodata.one/?&uuid=463e70d501bfb1f08b8496fb06161e7b21031fc2&layer=usgs_earthquakes_past_30_days_gd_178&linkId=0&ds=narimo%20web%20map%20service%20-%20USGS%20products&lang=de&rp=USGS) as WMS. The services are not free though (services need to be maintained) but the respective data is open data.

If you'd like to put it into a cool map app, I'm open to discussing usage options like free use for non-commercial applications. You also might be able to find more data here: [www.geodata.one](http://www.geodata.one).

The data contents include e.g. major volcanic eruptions, major tsunami locations (World); current river water levels, wind speed/ direction, rainfall amount, temperature, severe weather warnings, current radiation values (Germany).

Some of the data services are external, some still need to be set up or updated. If there is more relevant data out there, I will definitely add them (suggestions welcome).